# How to get the endpoint for kubernetes-dashboard

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I have installed kubernetes using minikube on ubuntu 16.04 machine.
I have also installed kubernetes-dashboard.
When i try accessing the dashboard i get

```
Waiting, endpoint for service is not registered yet
Waiting, endpoint for service is not ready yet...
Waiting, endpoint for service is not ready yet...
Waiting, endpoint for service is not ready yet...
.....
Could not find finalized endpoint being pointed to by kubernetes-dashboard: Temporary Error: Endpoint for service is not ready yet
Temporary Error: Endpoint for service is not ready yet
Temporary Error: Endpoint for service is not ready yet
Temporary Error: Endpoint for service is not ready yet
Temporary Error: Endpoint for service is not ready yet
Temporary Error: Endpoint for service is not ready yet

`
```

However, when i try a `kubectl get pods --all namespaces`i get the below output

```
    kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                                    READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   kube-addon-manager-minikube             1/1       Running   0          11m
kube-system   kube-dns-1301475494-xtb3b               3/3       Running   0          8m
kube-system   kubernetes-dashboard-2039414953-dvv3m   1/1       Running   0          9m
kube-system   kubernetes-dashboard-2crsk              1/1       Running   0          8m


   kubectl get endpoints --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                      ENDPOINTS                     AGE
default       kubernetes                10.0.2.15:8443                11m
kube-system   kube-controller-manager   <none>                        6m
kube-system   kube-dns                  172.17.0.4:53,172.17.0.4:53   8m
kube-system   kube-scheduler            <none>                        6m
kube-system   kubernetes-dashboard      <none>                        9m
```

How can i fix this issue? I don't seem to understand what is wrong. I am completely new to kubernetes

Comment: How did you install the dashboard?

Comment: @JanosLenart i used `kubectl create -f https://rawgit.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml`

Comment: Everything worked fine till yesterday. Today due to some issues with my network i had to re-start minikube. I did a `minikube stop --> minikube delete --> sudo rm -rf ~/.minikube --> minikube start` again. Since then i am facing this issue

Comment: I I see multiple dashbord pods running, can you paste this command output also ` kubectl get svc --all-namespaces`. you may have to remove and re-create dashboard service and pod.

Comment: @sfgroups you are right. I was also concerned with the two entries for the dashboard. I am new to kubernetes and didn't find any relevant guide to follow. So i unfortunately had to re-install k8s completely. Could you share some guides or commands that a beginner must know inorder to be comfortable with K8S an dminikube? That would help. Thanks

Comment: I use steps in this page to install miinikube https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube. after this we should be able to use kubectl command from the document website. I add commands from my notes.

Answer (score 3):

You need to run `minikube dashboard`. You shouldn't install dashboard separately; it comes with minikube.

Comment: I tried doing that but it said dashboard not found. That is the reason i installed it separately

Comment: Can you do `minikube addons list` please?

Comment: `-default storageclass : enabled -kube-dns: enabled -heapster: disabled -ingress:disabled -registry: disabled -registry-creds: disabled -addon-manager: enabled -dashboard:enabled`

Comment: Something similar. Even i added an entry to resolv.conf followed by a minikube stop and start. For now it seems to work. But it is very strange that this is happening. I am not sure if it will continue to work

Answer (score 1):

some of the minikube commands

```
./minikube.exe version
./minikube.exe delete 
./minikube.exe start --help
./minikube get-k8s-versions
./minikube.exe status
./minikube.exe ip
./minikube.exe dashboard --url=true
```